# how to load thymeleaf fragment into a js variable

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, fragment, thymeleaf

Started using ThymeLeaf with Spring Boot, and I am facing an issue in loading a simple fragment into a JS variable. Trying to append a row to a data table, where one of the cells should include a complex HTML portion. Something like this:

```
...
var cell_content = <Load thymeleaf fragment content with parameters>;
...
```

Now supposing that I have a ThymeLeaf fragment called: "x :: docs-popup" which includes a Bootstrap Popup for documents manipulation, How can I load the content of this popup, including passed parameters into the javascript variable cell_content, so that I append it to the generated row.

In other words, If I am using php, I would do the following:

```
 var cell_content = '<?php echo fragment_loader($document_object); ?>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question... in thymleaf 3, something like this works for me:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    cell_content = '[# th:insert="~{x :: docs-popup}"/]';
</script>
```

However, it doesn't automatically escape anything in the include.  So stray single quotes will break the javascript.

I would probably include it normally on the page (but make it `display: hidden`) by default and just refer to it by id.

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution didn't work for me, console.log(cell_content); shows the exact assigned string and does not load the fragment! do you have any idea why?
Adding the tags as hidden does not appear practical for my case, as I have a datatable where a lot of records could be in the page.

Comment: Are you using thymeleaf 3?  I'm not sure this syntax works for thymeleaf 2.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using Thymeleaf 2.1.5. Is there any workaround?!

Answer (score 0):

One straightforward way is to issue a call to a controller that returns the html of the fragment. See the doc [in the section about Fragment inclusion from Spring @Controller](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html)

```
// in your view
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/ 
   var url = /*[[@{/docs/}]]*/;
   $.get(url + param, function(fragment) {
          $rowDocPopup = $('...'); // get selector for the cell you need
          $rowDocPopup.replaceWith(fragment);
    });
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Then in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/docs/{id}")
public String reloadDocsPopup(@PathVariable Long id, Model model){
    // do stuff and put parameter data in model 
    return "templates/x :: docs-popup";
}
```